# @DataProvider with return type as Iterator<Object[]>

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-annotation-test

I try to execute the simple test case which call dataProvider and this dataProvider has return type as `Iterator<Object[]>`, I know this return type is not accept by `@DataProvider` method but after excute the below programm i get the blank output nothing is display in colsole,i accept at least message like the dataProvider is not exsist,please refer below program.

```
      public class Practice {


     @Test(dataProvider="NotWorking")
     public void testCase(Object[] obj)
      {
         System.out.println(obj[0]);
         System.out.println(obj[1]);
      }

@DataProvider(name="NotWorking")
public Iterator<Object[]> dataProvider2()
{
    List<Object[]> obj =new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] obj1=new Object[2];
    obj1[0]=new String("First_Object_First_value");
    obj1[1]=new String("First_Object_Second_value");
    Object[] obj2=new Object[2];
    obj2[0]=new String("Second_Object_First_value");
    obj1[1]=new String("Second_Object_Second_value");
    Iterator<Object[]> itr = obj.iterator();
    return itr;
       }
   }
```

i get the below output for above code,

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Comment: Good that you opened an issue in github. Posting the link for anyone to know the updates: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement

> dataProvider has return type as Iterator<Object[]>, i know this return type is not accept by @DataProvider method`.

This is actually **NOT** correct. `Iterator<Object[]>` is an **ACCEPTED** return type for a dataProvider in testNG.

So what is wrong with the above code is that, you are returning an **empty** `Iterator`.
Note the changes in the below code:

```java
@DataProvider(name="NotWorking")
public Iterator<Object[]> dataProvider2()
{
    List<Object[]> obj =new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] obj1=new Object[2];
    obj1[0]=new String("First_Object_First_value");
    obj1[1]=new String("First_Object_Second_value");
    Object[] obj2=new Object[2];
    obj2[0]=new String("Second_Object_First_value");
    obj2[1]=new String("Second_Object_Second_value"); // typo. used obj1 instead of obj2
    // You missed to add the below two lines
    obj.add(obj1);
    obj.add(obj2);
    Iterator<Object[]> itr = obj.iterator();
    return itr;
}
```

Now, after making the above changes, your test would work fine.

**NOTE: A test method will not be invoked if the data to that method is empty.**

**So next question - Why was the test was marked as ran but did not print anything.**

Answer: This depends on how an empty iterator is handled by testNG.
There is a difference between versions `7.3.0` and `7.4.0` itself. It would output as `Test run : 0` for `7.3.0` and as `Test run : 1` for `7.4.0`. There has been code changes in logging as part of the `7.4.0`. The test method count for `7.4.0` is taken from test context `context.getAllTestMethods()`, which contains the test you are running. For `7.3.0` it is taken from an array `m_allTestMethods` (which is empty).

Comment: Iterator<Object[]> is an ACCEPTED return type for a dataProvider  - in the end it's a object array nothing else. Why to make things complicated ?

Comment: @cruisepandey In this particular question it does not matter whether the return type is `Iterator<Object[]>`  or `Object[][]`. But iterator is helpful when you do not want to load data all together or if you want the test method to receive a particular object rather than a long set of parameters. `Iterator<Supplier>` or `Iterator<MyObject>` could be used for this.

Comment: @cruisepandey For simple use cases, it is enough to return `Object[][]`. But the point to note is that even if we return `Object[][]` testNG converts it to `Iterator<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `dataProviders` accept `object[]` as well. You can not use it for matrix data type but it is supported.

so if you have something like this :

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}
```

can be easily replace by

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[] createData1() {
 return new Object[] {
   { "Cedric"},
   { "Anne"},
 };
}
```

your `obj` is has a list of `Object` `arrays` and you are returning `obj.iterator();` which fulfils the dataProviders criteria.

Comment: ok thank for reply,but in how testNg should give some message in console and even is not execute the test case but still its says Tests run: 1, why?

Comment: @ankushpawar : that is because you are returning `obj.iterator();` and that does not have anything. You are storing values in `obj1` and `obj2` but not returning it.

Comment: ok thank you,please add  System.out.println("Test case"); this line in test method and try to get output you get  the same output,but here atleast this line get print but does not happen why?please help in this

Comment: @ankushpawar : Why are you violating the data Providers principle ? Check out what officials says about how to use dataProviders https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Comment: @cruisepandey which data provider principle is being violated? DataProvider allows `Iterator<Object[]>`

Comment: @GauthamM : dataProviders looks for object array so it does not matter how you return it. OP is not using it in correct manner, he is storing values in `obj1` and `obj2` and they are object array but while returning he is using `obj.iterator()` which does not have anything. So there's no error. But it's not useful, cause that exactly what dataProviders are not meant for.

Comment: @cruisepandey yes, OP had missed to add `obj1` and `obj2` to the `obj` list, If it was added, then the code would work as expected. But there are no violation of principles here. It is mentioned in the documentation as well.